# Why is my breaker tripping after hooking dishwasher back up?

Tags: circuit-breaker, dishwasher

I had to move my dishwasher, and in order to do that I had to disconnect it from power. I made a mental note of where the wires were before I disconnected and then put them back when I was done. Now, when I turn on the breaker for the dishwasher, it immediately trips. I replaced the breaker and it is doing the same thing.[image]

[image: Possible wire damage?]

Comment: Take the wire nut off the black side and separate them, use the wire nut to cap the feed wire by itself.  Now try the breaker, if it trips now the wire coming to the dishwasher is damaged somewhere.  If it doesn't trip, the problem is the dishwasher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest when reconnecting it the must be a short somewhere. Check all the cables are neat and terminated correctly and neatly.

Comment: I added an image in the Question. Seems neat. There is a small standoff between the ground wire and the metal box.

Comment: That's not a standoff. It's a retaining washer and should be *above* the wire, under the nut. It's not your problem, however. check the cable for damage, possibly along the dishwasher chassis.

Comment: Right. That's how it was originally was! Is it ok for the wire to touch the metal box or just the green screw and washer?

Comment: I just added an image. This is the only thing i can see that might be damage. The rest looked ok. I think maybe i was overzealous in securing the cable and crimped/tightened it too much.

Comment: The photo is a bit out of focus. Is that copper showing on the black wire? The ground wire should be sandwiched between the box and the washer with the tabs on it.

Comment: Yes. Copper was showing through on the black wire. I took everything apart and started over, and the breaker now stays on. I think maybe the ground was touching the box before it touched the ground screw. I did get the ground wrong (between the screw and the washer) after I hooked it back up the way it was originally (with the ground between the box and the washer like you said) because it wasn't working the other way.